# Can we define Kinetic Energy from non-inertial frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, work

I have read somewhere that Work Energy Theorem can be applied even from non-inertial frame by adding work done by pseudo force.

I further think that we need to take Kinetic Energy with reference to this frame for the theorem.

---

My question:

1. Is my thinking correct?
2. I find it a little absurd that "energy depends on frame". Please provide some arguments to
   justify/counter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read somewhere that Work Energy Theorem can be applied even from non-inertial frame by adding work done by pseudo force.

Yes, this is the case. The work-energy theorem results from Newton's second law, and pseudo-forces are what allow for Newton's second law to work in non-inertial reference frames. So the work-every theorem works fine in non-inertial reference frames. Pseudo-forces essentially allow you to treat non-inertial frames like inertial ones without Newton's third law.

> I find it a little absurd that "energy depends on frame". Please provide some arguments to justify/counter it.

Kinetic energy of a point particle is $\frac12mv^2$. Since $v$ is reference frame dependent, so is the kinetic energy.

As a simple example, if I see an object moving by me, I say it has kinetic energy. If you are removing with that object so that you see it as being at rest, then you would say it has no kinetic energy.